# Avoid cancel of postgresql script when losing connection to server due to VPN session closing

Tags: postgresql, vpn, putty

I'm trying to execute a remote postgresql script by command line (connecting to the server via putty) by using

```
\i myscript.sql
```

The problem comes when the script takes several hours to complete and VPN connection to the server (and consequently putty session) close. I can't really control that part because it's a local security policy. The session closing makes the execution of the script to cancel.

Is there an easy way to let the script run in the server regardless I'm still connected to it?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you putty in use GNU `screen` or one of its equivalents like `tmux` before you run psql.  This will preserve your session when you get disconnected so you just reconnect to it next time you log in.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the TCP keepalive idle time on your client operating system to have the client send “keepalive packets” regularly, which keeps the misconfigured firewall from closing the connection.

Start `psql` using the connection string syntax:

```sh
psql 'host=... port=5432 user=... dbname=... keepalives_idle=60s'
```